# Issue with Identity when switching to the Create view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

So I was following this tutorial: https://www.yogihosting.com/aspnet-core-identity-create-read-update-delete-users/ teaching how to make a CRUD for Identity users.

I've reached a point where I am getting 2 errors which I think are tied together. Firstly, I will present the code:

**AdminController.cs**

```
public ViewResult Create() => View();

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(User user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        AppUser appUser = new AppUser
        {
            UserName = user.Name,
            Email = user.Email
        };

        IdentityResult result = await userManager.CreateAsync(appUser, user.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        else
        {
            foreach (IdentityError error in result.Errors)
                ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description);
        }
    }
    return View(user);
}
```

**AppUser.cs**

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
}
```

When accessing the `localhost/Admin/Create' link after running the application, I am getting this error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Intersection.Models.AppUser]' while attempting to activate 'Filters.Controllers.AdminController'.
>
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)

Then, I figured that something might be wrong in the **Startup.cs**, therefore, after a bit of research, I added this line: `services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();`

In an attempt to fix the first error, I got this second issue:

> HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure

My **Startup.cs** class looks like this:

```
 public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddDbContext<AppIdentityDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]));
        services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

So what could be the issue? I tried following the tutorial closely but apparently I missed something out... Or things changed since it was posted. Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure

This was due to methods `AddDbContext` and `AddIdentity` having duplicates in the **Startup.cs**. After commenting out the duplicates, I got rid of it.

Secondly, in **_LoginPartial.cshtml**, I had this:

```
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager
```

I had to replace `IdentityUser` with my `AppUser`. This fixed the first error.